# How to evaluate a matlab symbolic expression properly?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Lets say I have a matrix like this:

```
syms p;
K = [p^2+3 0; 2 5*p];
p_initial = 2;
```

Whats the proper/fastest way of getting K(p_initial), that is the resulting matrix if I insert 2 for p. Further, I want the resulting matrix to be of type double, not of symbolic type.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using Google **before** stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`subs`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) to substitute variables in symbolic expressions

```
subs(K,'p',p_initial)

ans =

[ 7,  0]
[ 2, 10]
```

Comment: And then just using double() on the result?

Comment: Thanks, I actually did though: "Further, I want the resulting matrix to be of type double, not of symbolic type.".